# Can I do this with data.table without using the merge() function?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

I work with very huge datasets and I'm trying to speed up my R code.
Here is an example of data :

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(100,101,102,103, 104), sex = c("m","f","m","m","f"), 
value = c(32,14,32,03,03))

data look like this :
    id sex value
1: 100   m    32
2: 101   f    14
3: 102   m    32
4: 103   m     3
5: 104   f     3
```

The final output I want :

```
   value f.value m.value f   m
1:     3    1       1    1   1
2:    14    1       NA   1   NA
3:    32    NA      2    NA  2
```

The code I currently use :

```
dt_u <- unique(dt, by = c("id", "sex", "value"))
dt_u <- dt_u[, .(n = .N), keyby = .(value, sex)]
dt_u <- dcast(dt_u, value ~ sex, value.var = "n")
dt_t <- dt[, .(n = .N), keyby = .(value, sex)]
dt_t <- dcast(dt_t, value ~ sex, value.var = "n")
dt <- merge(dt_t, dt_u, by = "value", all = TRUE)
```

The code is working great, the problem is that the merging of dt_u and dt_t can take a lot of time on 10GB + data. So my question is : **Is it possible to get the same final output without having to "split" the data and then merging it?**

Also I would like the answer to be in data.table if possible,
thank you.

EDIT : example and explaination. The ID represent a person, this person can go to the same location (value) more than one time. For this example you can say that each value represent a different city.

IE:

```
dt <- data.table(value = c(21,21,21,21,21,40,1,22,1,1,22, 22, 49, 
49,21,21,1,1,1), id = 
c(1000716624,1000722724,1000716624,1000746824,1001012024,
1002067324,1002743624,1002743645, 1002743636, 
1002743423,1000716624,1000722724, 1000722724,1001012024, 
1000716624,1000716624,1002743624,1002743624,1002743624), sex = c("f", "m", 
"m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m", "f","f","f", "m", 
"m", "m"))
```

Output :

```
 value   places_women   places_men  number_women   number_men
1:     1            1          5            1          2
2:    21            4          3            2          3
3:    22            2          1            2          1
4:    40            1         NA            1         NA
5:    49            1          1            1          1
```

Comment: not sure I would ever put myself through using R with 10GB of data at any time - but could you not just loop through both columns (iterrows in python) and create a map/dictionary of the items. Where you have something like `{3: {'f': 1, 'm':1}}` etc. You only have to loop through once. then compute and update the counters.

Comment: Couple questions. Is your overall goal to count the number of `m` and `f` associated with each value (returning `NA` for non-matches)? Does this `id` column matter? Is there any situation where `f.value` and `m.value` would not mirror `f` and `m` in your expected output.

Comment: @Chinny84 Hi, my job require me to use R so I have to stick with it, altough I agree that R can be a little capricious with huge data. Your answer seems like it could definitively work, I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew 1. Yes, altough there is no NA in the real data set (millions of rows). 2. Yes, the id column is important since the unique(id) gives me the number of people. The id column actually gives me the number of time someone went somewhere (so I compare the number of people by sex with the place they went to). 3. Normally they should mirror f and m. Thanks.

Comment: ```f.value m.value f   m``` why you have duplicated columns?

Comment: @M-M those are not duplicate. I should have named them differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for the second example (based on reverse engineering the desired output):

```
> dcast(dt, value ~ sex, value.var=list("value", "id"), fun=list(length, uniqueN), fill=NA)
   value value.1_length_f value.1_length_m id_uniqueN_f id_uniqueN_m
1:     1                1                5            1            2
2:    21                4                3            2            3
3:    22                2                1            2            1
4:    40                1               NA            1           NA
5:    49                1                1            1            1
```

A more explicit description of what calculations are supposed to be in each column (and maybe more natural column names in the example) would help if this doesn't work for the full problem.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = c(100,101,102,103, 104), sex = c("m","f","m","m","f"), 
                 value = c(32,14,32,03,03))

dcast(unique(unique(dt, 
                    by = c("id", "sex", "value"))[ , 

            count := .N, by = list(value,sex)][,
        id:=NULL]), 
value ~ sex, value.var = "count")

#>    value  f  m
#> 1:     3  1  1
#> 2:    14  1 NA
#> 3:    32 NA  2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I get the ``f.value`` and ``m.value`` tho?

Comment: @Gainz Are those just duplicates of `f` and `m` columns? I still dunno what's the different between `s.value` and `s`?

Comment: No, sorry. I should have named them differently. Since the example contain only a few values it looks like they are duplicated. I'll change the name in my question.

Comment: @Gainz Let's put the naming issue aside. Their value is exactly as same as `f` and `m` in your expected output. Are you still counting by `list(value,sex)`? If so, they are duplicates.

Comment: Yes because the example doesn't contain enough data. I'll try to add a better example.

Comment: Yeah I edited the question, thank you for the answer, your code was still an improvement over mine!

Comment: @Gainz you are fine. No worries.